# Clean code - calling one locked section from another

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm reading Uncle Bob's Clean Code and the conclusion of chapter 13 includes the following:

> Do not lock regions of code that do not need to be locked. Avoid calling one locked section from another.

Why the recommendation to not call one locked section from another (assuming you hold a reentrant lock)? It seems perfectly feasible to me.

Comment: I assume it is meant that calling one locked section from another locked section, which use different locks, will cause deadlock potential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Avoid calling one locked section from another.

Refers to sections locked by different locks, if you don't acquire the lock in the same order then you have a potential cause of deadlocks. You can find an interesting example of this problem in the [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html).

Comment: I thought just as much, but unfortunately, the text didn't clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to lock 2 or more objects simultaneously, you have no other way to call one locking section from another.
To avoid deadlocks, always lock objects in the same order.